# Android OS - custom roms - is it safe?

Tags: android, operating-system, cyanogenmod

I just wanted to know is it really safe to sign into your google account through custom roms without risking leakage/ stolen password or having your google account stolen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will depend on the custom ROM in question. Basically, I suggest you stick to the well-known ones, such as CyanogenMod and Modaco (and others, according to your device). When working with an unknown ROM, I usually use a newly created google account for the testing.

Comment: I have been using a custom rom (SwiftDroid Project - O.S. 2.3.2, by Mur4ik) based on cyanogenmod 7 for the LG gt540 http://bit.ly/icVFTx. Currently I'm using a test google account and everything seems to be working fine. The rom itself is quite popular and seems to be doing well. In any-case, so the developer can do a hack to steal passwords/accounts if he/she wishes to?

Comment: Yes, they can. But most ROMs don't change too much of the AOSP code. Your ROM, specifically, should be safe engough, though.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're about to install CyanogenMod, as the question is tagged with it. No need to worry about it, CyanogenMod is used by many.

If you'd like to secure your Google account further, take a look at [2-step verification](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/SmsAuthConfig), and enable it for your Google Account.
This does however not fully protect you - as some applications still require application-specific passwords to be used, unfortunately Android is included here. It does however protect you from others stealing your password when logging on from a public computer.